# Oracle installation error: "DBCA_PROGRESS : DBCA Operation failed."

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I tried to install Oracle 12c on CentOS VM (no docker), in the final step "Oracle Database Configuration", I got the error "DBCA_PROGRESS : DBCA Operation failed."

The VM has 64GB RAM, 500GB hard disk. All yum packages are up to date.

```
INFO: Read: Copying database files
INFO: Copying database files
WARNING: Skipping line: Copying database files
INFO: Read: 1% complete
WARNING: Skipping line: 1% complete
INFO: Read: 13% complete
WARNING: Skipping line: 13% complete
INFO: Read: 25% complete
WARNING: Skipping line: 25% complete
INFO: Read: Creating and starting Oracle instance
INFO: Creating and starting Oracle instance
WARNING: Skipping line: Creating and starting Oracle instance
INFO: Read: 26% complete
WARNING: Skipping line: 26% complete
INFO: Read: 27% complete
WARNING: Skipping line: 27% complete
INFO: Read: 31% complete
WARNING: Skipping line: 31% complete
INFO: Read: 32% complete
WARNING: Skipping line: 32% complete
INFO: Read: DBCA Operation failed.
INFO: DBCA Operation failed.
WARNING: Skipping line: DBCA Operation failed.
INFO: Read: Look at the log file "/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/orcl/orcl1.log" for further details.
INFO: Look at the log file "/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/orcl/orcl1.log" for further details.
WARNING: Skipping line: Look at the log file "/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/orcl/orcl1.log" for further details.
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Database Configuration Assistant
INFO: Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed.
INFO: Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed.
INFO: ConfigClient.executeSelectedToolsInAggregate action performed
INFO: Exiting ConfigClient.executeSelectedToolsInAggregate method
INFO: 
 The Runconfig command constructed is /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/oui/bin/runConfig.sh ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1 MODE=perform ACTION=configure RERUN=false $*
INFO: Since the option is to overwrite the existing /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/cfgtoollogs/configToolFailedCommands file, backing it up
INFO: The backed up file name is /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/cfgtoollogs/configToolFailedCommands.bak.3
INFO: Adding ExitStatus SUCCESS_MINUS_RECTOOL to the exit status set
INFO: ConfigClient.saveSession method called
INFO: Calling event ConfigSessionEnding
INFO: ConfigClient.endSession method called
INFO: Completed Configuration
INFO: Waiting for completion of background operations
INFO: Finishing all forked tasks at state setup
INFO: Waiting for completion all forked tasks at state setup
INFO: All forked task are completed at state setup
INFO: Completed background operations
INFO: Validating view at state <setup>
INFO: Completed validating view at state <setup>
INFO: Validating state <setup>
WARNING: [WARNING] [INS-32091] Software installation was successful. But some configuration assistants failed, were cancelled or skipped.
   ACTION: Refer to the logs or contact Oracle Support Services.
```

here's the log /u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/orcl/orcl1.log

```
[ 2018-12-06 09:53:11.079 HKT ] Copying database files
DBCA_PROGRESS : 1%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 13%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 25%
[ 2018-12-06 09:57:18.931 HKT ] Creating and starting Oracle instance
[ 2018-12-06 09:59:41.219 HKT ] ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

DBCA_PROGRESS : 26%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 27%
[ 2018-12-06 09:59:42.666 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:42.670 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:42.674 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:42.687 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:42.699 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

DBCA_PROGRESS : 31%
[ 2018-12-06 09:59:42.704 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:42.713 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:42.717 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:42.720 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:42.722 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

DBCA_PROGRESS : 32%
[ 2018-12-06 09:59:44.045 HKT ] ORA-01012: not logged on

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:45.309 HKT ] ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:45.312 HKT ] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:46.615 HKT ] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:47.899 HKT ] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:49.174 HKT ] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:49.179 HKT ] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

[ 2018-12-06 09:59:55.551 HKT ] DBCA_PROGRESS : DBCA Operation failed.
```

Comment: CentOS is not supported by Oracle for 12c. https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/oracle-linux-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Increasing docker memory worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Such an ORA-03113 is typically caused by your database server process terminating unexpectedly due to a critical error.

Look at the database alert log: `/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/orcl/orcl/trace/alert_ORCL.log` for details.

It seems not only your session, but the instance crashed as well. This is a typical issue on CentOS/RHEL with default settings:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E67200/html/section-t51_kcn_f5.html

> If RemoveIPC=yes is configured for systemd, interprocess communication
>   (IPC) is terminated for a non-system user's processes when that user
>   logs out. This setting, which is intended for laptops, can cause
>   software problems on server systems. For example, if the user is a
>   database software owner such as oracle for Oracle Database, this
>   configuration **can cause database installation to fail or database
>   services to crash**.
>
> ...
>
> To avoid database crashes, set RemoveIPC=no in
>   /etc/systemd/logind.conf and run systemctl reboot to reboot the
>   system.

If you see errors similar to the ones below, you have encountered that issue.

```
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:semctl failed with status: 22
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Invalid argument
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sskgpwrm1
ORA-27157: OS post/wait facility removed
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:semop failed with status: 36
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Identifier removed
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sskgpwwait1
```